# Data Flow with React/Redux and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux

I have a React/Redux front-end with an Express back-end application, and I'm rather new, but I have a question regarding how to deal with the flow of data.

So, on my front end side, I have a search bar. When a user enters a search term, I sent a post request from React which is handled in my Express routes.js file. In this file, I am taking that search term, and I am looking for that term in my Mongo database. After that, all I want to do is send an object back if the term was found in the database.

I have used *axios* in this application to make an HTTP request to a certain route to pull off some data, but that was within an `app.get(...)` on the express side, and I used an `axios.get(...)` on the React side to retrieve the information.

But, this situation is slightly different since the data is flowing in two directions. Initially, from a front end to the backend, and then back-end to front-end. And in this case, I'm using `app.post(...)`.

**Now my question is**, how would I retrieve the data to the front end? Could I simply just do an `axios.get(...)` on an `app.post(...)` or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you GET from the browser to your back-end's route which is implemented to respond to POST only, you will probably get a 405 error. Implement a POST Axios request and a POST Express reply.

Comment: I looked up axios post requests, but I'm not posting any data I was just want to retrieve data from an earlier post request. I believe the first argument wants me to send some sort of an object as a post request. But I don't want that

Comment: You can't get data from "an earlier request" from the server. Why don't you store this data on the client side?

Comment: That's precisely my issue. I think I have a misunderstanding in what I am doing. How do I get the data from my express post route, back to my client side react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `GET` or `POST`, but you need to be consistent on the server and the client side. If you do an http `GET` from the client, the server will only respond if you have a `app.get(...)` as a server route.

As far as the flow of data is concerned, both a get and a post can return data, it just needs to be specified on the express route.

After the business logic of looking if the key exists in mongo do something like `res.send({'found': true})` or `res.json({'found': false})`. This will ensure that the data gets back to the client.

Comment: Yes, so once i res.send() the data onto the post request route. How am I going to get that route on the client side. Axios.get() wouldn't work the same way would it? But there's also an axios.post() but I dont want to post anymore data, and the first argument is an object I think.

Comment: @PhillipR it will be done automatically.  If you are using promises it will look something like 

`axios.get('/term/wordimlookingfor')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });`

The `then` will contain the response from express.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would:

1.) Use an [Axios get request and pass in as a parameter](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params) the identifying attributes, such as a related _id or key phrase.

2.) Use  [mongoDB's query filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) search parameters to index and aggregate the schema data in the DB. I would probably use [.findOne or .find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).

3.) Use the router callback to pass in the filtered data, then [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) a function to save it to a state.

This way you can set up specific terms or keywords to search with, and utilize the searched data throughout the app.